# JavaFX code gui does not do what code suggests

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javafx

I am writing a JavaFX project which is intended to show the Olympic rings with their correct interlocks on a non-resizeable window. I have written code which is included at the end of this post however each time it is run it displays as follows (and is resizable):

[image]

This is my first javaFX project and I would appreciate any advice on where I am going wrong.
Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class OlympicRings extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage

    primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Olympic Rings");

        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        // create 5 ellipses
        Ellipse e1 = new Ellipse(60, 40);
        e1.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        e1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        e1.setStrokeWidth(2);

        Ellipse e2 = new Ellipse(80, 50);
        e2.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
        e2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        e2.setStrokeWidth(2);

        Ellipse e3 = new Ellipse(100, 60);
        e3.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        e3.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        e3.setStrokeWidth(2);

        Ellipse e4 = new Ellipse(120, 70);
        e4.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        e4.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        e4.setStrokeWidth(2);

        Ellipse e5 = new Ellipse(140, 80);
        e5.setFill(Color.RED);
        e5.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        e5.setStrokeWidth(2);

        // create 5 rectangles
        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(60, 20);
        r1.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        r1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        r1.setStrokeWidth(2);

        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(80, 30);
        r2.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
        r2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        r2.setStrokeWidth(2);

        Rectangle r3 = new Rectangle(100, 40);
        r3.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        r3.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        r3.setStrokeWidth(2);

        Rectangle r4 = new Rectangle(120, 50);
        r4.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        r4.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        r4.setStrokeWidth(2);

        Rectangle r5 = new Rectangle(140, 60);
        r5.setFill(Color.RED);
        r5.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        r5.setStrokeWidth(2);

        // create a text
        Text t = new Text("The Olympic Rings");
        t.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 16px;");

        // put all the shapes together
        root.getChildren().addAll(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, t);

        // create a scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);

        // set the scene on the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        // show the stage
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: use combinations of arcs rather than circles or ellipses, otherwise you will be unable to achieve the interlocking of the rings. JavaFX follows the [painter’s algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm), understand both its advantages and limitations and work with them.

Comment: Also, check the argument values that you pass to the [ellipse constructor that you are using](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Ellipse.html#%3Cinit%3E(double,double)) in your code.  Your argument values have different radiuses in the x and y direction, which isn't what you want for a circle.  Instead, you could use a Circle if you don't care about getting the interlocking right.  But as I indicated, you will need to use Arcs if you want the correct interlocking behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't arranged a position for the shapes, use a different constructors to organise the relative size and positions of the shapes:

```
new Ellipse(double centerX, double centerY, double radiusX, double radiusY)
new Rectangle(double x, double y, double width, double height)
```

As you are using a StackPane they may be aligned one over the other. Instead you could add all the components to a Group then put the single group into the pane:

```
final Group g = new Group();
g.getChildren().addAll(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, t);
root.getChildren().addAll(g);
```